# extracting git orphan branches into standalone repos

Tags: git

I've got a single git repo with multiple orphan branches containing their own separate and unrelated history. Structure is similar to

```
C:\repos\original-git-repo>git branch
   orphan1
  *orphan2
   orphan3
```

This has turned out to be a poor structure for my workflow.

How do I easily extract each of these orphan branches into standalone repos while (a) maintaining each orphan's branch history, and (b) each new standalone repo contains only the objects from it's matching orphan branch, not all objects from the original repo?

Resulting dir tree of git repos would look like

```
C:\repos>
   |- original-git-repo/
   |- orphan1/
   |- orphan2/
   `- orphan3/
```

**UPDATE:** as mentioned below, a normal clone of the original repo appears to clone all objects into the new repo's `.git/objects` dir rather than just the objects for a specific orphan branch. The best I've been able to do for minimal new repo size is this overly manual recipe for each original orphan branches.

```
$ git init [--bare] <new repo>
# push orphan branch from orig to new repo as `push.default = current` in config
$ git remote add <new repo name> <path>
$ git push <new repo name>
# manually copy relevant tags from orig repo to new repo's `.git/refs/tags` dir
```

Cloning using `--local --no-hardlinks --branch orphan1 --single-branch` also appears to clone all orig repo objects into new repo even though only one local/remote branch pair is cloned.

**UPDATE2 - PREFERRED SOLUTION:** As both answers below show, one can solve this in multiple ways via `git init`, or `git clone` and some manual editing of `.git/packed-refs`. I'm using this recipe based upon the accepted answer from below.

```
git init orphan1
cd orphan1
git fetch C:/repos/original-git-repo orphan1:orphan1
git checkout orphan1
git branch -m master
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch anything you want with just a url and refname

```
git init orphan1
cd orphan1
git fetch /path/to/original orphan1:orphan1
```

and likewise with the others.

Comment: this works perfectly with no surprise side effects. From the orig repo, it fetches only the required objects, any corresponding tags, and does no packing. I'm updating my question with a simple add to your recipe that renames the new repo's `orphan1` branch to `master`.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy. Basically, for each branch, you just have to create a copy of the repo, set the desired branch as "master", delete the others, and remove loose objects:

```
$ git clone <original repo> <new repo>
$ git remote rm origin  # Optionally remove reference to original repo
$ git checkout <desired branch>
$ git branch -m master
# Delete all unwanted branches
# Optionally, remove all unreachable objects:
$ git prune --expire=now
$ git gc --aggressive
```

Comment: This should work but doesn't. Cloning the original (no packed) repo with tags pulls all objects (684 in my test case) into `.git/objects` and creates a `.git/packed-refs` containing all the `.git/refs/tags/*` tags pulled down from the original repo.

Comment: Hit enter too early...Cloning the orig repo (non packed) repo with tags pulls all objects (684 in my test case) into `.git/objects` and creates a `.git/packed-refs` containing all the `.git/refs/tags/*` tags pulled down from the orig repo. Best I've been able to do is `git init [--bare] <new repo>` then `git push <new repo>` from the orig repo (with `push.default=current` config). This gives me 52 objects in new repo's `.git/objects`. I then manually copy tags I want into new repos `.git/refs/tags`. Got to be a better way.

Comment: @Jon: Did you run `git prune` and `git gc`?

Comment: yes I ran gc and prune in sequence as you suggested. I also thought these would purge all unused objects after deleting the unwanted branches. My working theory now is that since `git clone` creates a `.git/packed-refs` file in the new repo with all tags and orphan branch refs (eg `<sha1> refs/remotes/origin/orphan1` from orig repo, this causes prune/gc/fsck to **not** view the referenced objects as unreachable. I'm starting from scratch to investigate.

Comment: Using new repo's `.git/packed-refs` (created from `git clone`) as-is prevents prune from removing the unused objects. In your recipe, if I edit `.git/packed-refs` to include only the tags corresponding to the single branch I want and then run `git prune` and `git gc`, the 684 originally cloned objects are pruned down to 52 and packed as we both would expect.